# Try out Intel TSX

Tags: cloud, cpu, intel, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

I want to try out Intel's transactional memory capabilities, but I don't want to have to buy a brand new server to do it.  Are there any cloud services that have CPUS that support TSX?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's C4 [instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) use Haswell processors which support TSX.

Comment: Presumably these instances have TSX disabled because the implementation was buggy. ["The bug was fixed in F-0 steppings of the vPro-enabled Core M-5Y70 Broadwell CPU in November 2014."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions#Implementation)